# If Date is today, "update" the database, else "insert into"

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a query that runs at button click.
I want to set it up so if the system date = "DateColumn" to update the Database.
Else
To Insert Into.

```
    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    dataFile = ("Database\Base-Original.accdb")

    Using myconnection As New OleDbConnection(provider & dataFile)
        myconnection.Open()

        Dim sqlQry1 As String = "INSERT INTO [Table] ([Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4], [Date]) VALUES (@1, @2, @3, @4, @5)"

        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQry1, myconnection)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", Combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", textbox1.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", Textbox2.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", Combobox2.SelectedItem.ToString)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@5", Date.Now.ToShortDateString)

            If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() Then
                myconnection.Close()
                MsgBox("successfull. ", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Record Saved")
            Else
                MsgBox("failed. ", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Registration failed")
                Return
            End If

        End Using

    End Using
```

I have the INSERT INTO, but I have no idea how to go about Updating the database instead of inserting a new record... I do know how to update, but I'd like to have 1 record with column name (Column1) once per day.

Do I need to use reader to check the date column?
Or is there another way to go... I only need to be pointed in the right direction.
~much appreciated..

Comment: Why cant you check if there is such a record and act accordingly?  `AddWithValue` is a bad idea and saving dates as strings is a very, very bad idea

Comment: I don't know how to. I know that I should check whether there is a record with column1 and date.today then use if there is, update it, if there isn't create new.

Comment: Then thats what you need to research.  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/

Comment: I understand that I should use the Select from table where Column1 = something and Date = something. What I don't know is how to set it that IF date is today, then update, else insert... I'm also having mismatch errors trying to check if date is today...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating Data in Database MS Access vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414574/updating-data-in-database-ms-access-vb-net)

Comment: I wanted to say you need this and that... but I have to say, I have help for you. HERE https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815629 If you would google instead of posting questions here, you would become better developer. That page has everything you need. The problem is that you asked same question that has been answered numerous times. my suggestion is do your research, don't make us do it for you. While researching, you will polish your knowledge

Comment: I did research for 20+ hours before I came asking :S I am making progress, but it seems I cannot get to check if date is "Today" it comes back as data mismatch... I probably need to parse the date to the same format access uses or something, thanks for the link.

Comment: **#1 mistake** you making - **treat date as string** --> `Date.Now.ToShortDateString`. Always save datetime --> `Date.Now`. **#2 - avoid pitfalls** - Datetime has time component, which sometimes detrimental in comparing dates. I saved my item on 1/1/2010 2:35:23. I am looking for items I saved on 1//12010. --> use time trimming/date converting functions to strip time component

Comment: Makes sense, I'll give it a try, and post update.

Comment: Unless I treat date as string, I always get data mismatch. There is no way to save Date.Now in access as is. And when I use 'Dim T as string = Date.Now' and use this to insert record, it works. But whether I use this or not, whenever I call the 'SELECT' statement, it comes out as data mismatch. ("SELECT Column1, Dats FROM Table WHERE Column1 = '" & Combobox1.SelectedItem & "' AND Dats = '" & Date.Today & "'", myconnection) I can't make this one to work... The select statement.

Comment: I made it work with datetimepicker.  I can now use the datetimepicker to insert update at whatever date I want :) It also more  useful this way. Thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 0):

This code here will search the database for a record that has a date value equal to today's date (*See important note below*). If one is found, the value fields are updated and saved back to the database.

```
    Private Sub SOExample2()
    Using myconnection As New OleDbConnection(provider & dataFile)
        myconnection.Open()
        Dim TodaysRecordSQL As String = String.Format("SELECT [Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4], [Date] FROM [Table] WHERE [Date] = '{0:o}' ORDER BY [Date] DESC", Date.Today.Date)
        Dim UpdateDS As New DataSet
        Using UpdateDA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(TodaysRecordSQL, myconnection)
            UpdateDA.Fill(UpdateDS)
        End Using
        Dim UpdateTable As DataTable = UpdateDS.Tables("Table")
        If UpdateTable IsNot Nothing AndAlso UpdateTable.Rows.Count = 1 Then
            ' Update existing record
            Dim UpdateRow As DataRow = UpdateTable.Rows(0)
            UpdateRow("Column1") = "NewValue1"
            UpdateRow("Column2") = "NewValue2"
            Using UpdateDA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter()
                Using UpdateCmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
                    UpdateCmd.Connection = myconnection
                    UpdateCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Table] SET [Column1] = @1, [Column2] = @2, [Column3] = @3, [Column4] = @4 WHERE [Date] = @5"
                    Dim UpdateParam As OleDb.OleDbParameter = New OleDb.OleDbParameter()
                    UpdateParam.ParameterName = "@1"
                    UpdateParam.SourceColumn = "Column1"
                    UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add(UpdateParam)

                    UpdateParam = New OleDb.OleDbParameter()
                    UpdateParam.ParameterName = "@2"
                    UpdateParam.SourceColumn = "Column2"
                    UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add(UpdateParam)

                    UpdateParam = New OleDb.OleDbParameter()
                    UpdateParam.ParameterName = "@3"
                    UpdateParam.SourceColumn = "Column3"
                    UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add(UpdateParam)

                    UpdateParam = New OleDb.OleDbParameter()
                    UpdateParam.ParameterName = "@4"
                    UpdateParam.SourceColumn = "Column4"
                    UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add(UpdateParam)

                    UpdateParam = New OleDb.OleDbParameter()
                    UpdateParam.ParameterName = "@5"
                    UpdateParam.SourceColumn = "Date"
                    UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add(UpdateParam)

                    UpdateDA.UpdateCommand = UpdateCmd
                    UpdateDA.Update(UpdateDS) ' This does the actual updating of the modified rows in the DataSet
                End Using
            End Using
        Else
            ' Insert new record
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

**NOTE:** This code is assuming that you're saving your records to the database with a timestamp of 00:00 hours (aka midnight).  If the saved record had a time of 14:12 (2:12 PM), as an example, then it would be trickier to find "today's" record as you have no idea of what the time portion of "today's" entry might be.